# how to update 2 linked tables in sql server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2016

I have two tables, there is a foreign key relationship defined between the two tables. If I attempt to update the second table, I receive the following error:

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK__T2__owner__48CFD27E". The conflict occurred in database "MY_DB",
>   table "dbo.T2", column 'T2.colomn1'.

How can I update the column in the second table that references the first table?

Comment: Can you show your update statement as well as the schemas of both tables?

Comment: Is this for mysql, mssql or postgressql?

Comment: @Simon it's sql server 2016

Comment: @WEI_DBA here UPDATE post_office
 SET [address] ='tehran p 190' , postal_code = '1234567891'
 WHERE social_id = '0020366760';   i actually changed some names in the question but the don't makes any differance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably isn't necessary to update both tables, in fact there's a good chance you don't want to. Based on your comment, I'm assuming you have a postal_code table? It seems less likely that you would have a foreign key on address but I suppose it's possible. The reason you don't want to update both is that other rows in your `post_office` table may use the same `postal_code`.

Simply add your new postal code to the `postal_code` table. (I've guessed at the name.)

```
INSERT INTO postal_code
VALUES ('1234567891')
```

Then do your update.

```
UPDATE post_office
SET address = 'Tehran p 190', postal_code = '1234567891'
WHERE social_id = '0020366760'
```

If you don't think any other post offices use the old postal_code you can always clean up after yourself.

```
DELETE FROM postal_code
WHERE id = 'someid'
```

Comment: thank you so much,it was great idea :) saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

- When you are trying to update the entry in table T1, make sure that the value with which we are updating in a column that has foreign key reference, you update with values that are there in the referenced foreign keys table(Unless the column is nullable).
- The value with which you are trying to update T2,column1 should be already present in T1.column2.

Comment: actually i can't change any column from T2 because it references to T1 .and when i'm trying to change one of them,sql server doesn't allow or just give me some errors.